# removing jtable grid (cell border) completely

Tags: java, swing, jtable, border, cell

How can I remove the border around the cells in a swing JTable completely, so the cells have no gaps between them?
Here is what I have tried:

```
table.setShowGrid(false);
table.setShowVerticalLines(false);
table.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
```

and writing a cell renderer and using:

```
setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
```

for each individual cell.

But the result is the lines between the cells are removed but a 1 pixel gap is left between them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> and writing a cell renderer and using:

everything depends what Renderer returns but without Renderer works for me

- setIntercellSpacing()
- setShowGrid()

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableExample {

    public TableExample() {
        Object[][] data1 = new Object[50][5];
        for (int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
            data1[i][0] = "Company # " + (i + 1);
            for (int j = 1; j < data1[i].length; j++) {
                data1[i][j] = "" + (i + 1) + ", " + j;
            }
        }
        String[] headers = {"Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3", "Col 4", "Col 5"};
        DefaultTableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel(data1, headers);
        final JTable jTable3 = new TableBackroundPaint0(data1, headers);
        //final JTable jTable3 = new JTable(data1, headers);
        jTable3.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jTable3.setModel(model1);
        final JScrollPane sp3 = new JScrollPane();
        sp3.setViewportView(jTable3);
        jTable3.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0, 0));
        jTable3.setShowGrid(false);
        //jTable3.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(jTable3.getPreferredSize());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("tableSelection");
        frame.add(sp3);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableExample te = new TableExample();
            }
        });
    }
}

class TableBackroundPaint0 extends JTable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    TableBackroundPaint0(Object[][] data, Object[] head) {
        super(data, head);
        setOpaque(false);
        ((JComponent) getDefaultRenderer(Object.class)).setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Color background = new Color(168, 210, 241);
        Color controlColor = new Color(230, 240, 230);
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Paint oldPaint = g2.getPaint();
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, background, width, 0, controlColor));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g2.setPaint(oldPaint);
        for (int row : getSelectedRows()) {
            Rectangle start = getCellRect(row, 0, true);
            Rectangle end = getCellRect(row, getColumnCount() - 1, true);
            g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(start.x, 0, controlColor, (int) ((end.x + end.width - start.x) * 1.25), 0, Color.orange));
            g2.fillRect(start.x, start.y, end.x + end.width - start.x, start.height);
        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, that you have to call the `setIntercellSpacing()` method _after_ you set a column model (if you choose to do so), because it basically calls `setColumnMargin()` on the _current_ `TableColumnModel` and `setRowMargin()` on the `JTable` itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can just set color of border to background color of cell. Also, please have a look at these examples,

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/CellBorderTableExample.htm

http://www.esus.com/docs/GetQuestionPage.jsp?uid=1290

Answer (score 2):

You can use these methods in JTable in order to remove the grid if your column models are not auto generating (without data binding).

```
 setShowGrid(false);
 setRowMargin(0);
 setShowVerticalLines(false);
 setShowHorizontalLines(false);
```

But If you created column models using data binding then you have trouble. That is even if you call these methods their is still paint white 1 pixel gap in each column margin.

You can remove that column margin by using custom DefaultTableColumnModel.

```
 private class CustomDefaultTableColumnModel extends DefaultTableColumnModel{

 @Override
 public void setColumnMargin(int newMargin) {
    //Always set ColumnMargin to zero.
    //Because after the column data binding its internally set one as ColumnMargin.
   //That course to paint white color grid.
   //To stop we override the setColumnMargin and pass zero to ColumnMargin.
  super.setColumnMargin(0);
  }
}
```

Then you can add your custom table column model into your table.

```
 setColumnModel(new CustomDefaultTableColumnModel());
```

Comment: This is the best solution to avoid to have that nasty white color 1 pixel grid in the selected row. Maybe i would recommend to override getColumnMargin to return 0 always, instead of overriding setColumnMargin method, but it's very close.